# Remove old version automatically when Installing new one

Tags: android, version

I have already developed one app version 1.0 and also published it. In few days, I am going to publish my second app version 1.2.

As I checked it, Whenever I install new version App over old, It asked me to uninstall old app first. So is there anyway by which, whenever I install new app, it automatically uninstall old one and then install new one?

Comment: `As I checked it,` how are you doing this?

Comment: I guess you have use the same package name for both the application. If so, use different package name in second application. Android identifies unique application from the package.

Comment: I don't think so i need to use different package name.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the two versions were signed with different keys (for example a production key and a debug key). If they are both signed with the same key this will not happen. Make sure the existing and new versions were both signed with the same key.

Comment: Still I have not signed my application. It is in testing mode. And I am installing it directly on my mobile device.

Comment: What about version 1.0? Was this developed with the same key? You say it was published already...1.2 needs to be signed with the same key as 1.0 was for the upgrade to work without this message.

Comment: ohhh, then I will need to check it by signing new version. I signed 1.0 version then published it.

Comment: Correct. Android will warn you otherwise. This is a security feature. I usually simulate a market upgrade by signing my new version with my production key, uploading it to my phone, then clicking on the file in a file viewer like es file explorer. This launches the install/upgrade dialog. Just make sure the new version is uploaded to the market signed with the same production key as 1.0 and you will be fine.

Comment: If you change package name, it's regarded as a different app. So, NO for your purpose.